# Confidence Intervals for Weighted Survey Analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, survey

I'm interested in using confidence intervals calculated from the survey package, as is done here:

```
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, fpc=~fpc, data=apiclus1)

df <- svyciprop(~I(ell==0), dclus1, method="li")
str(df)
```

I am having trouble assigning this to an object for later use, though, and it seems as if the only way I can get it out is by copying and pasting, which can't possibly be true.

How do I create a dataframe from this object so that I can use the confidence intervals elsewhere?

I would like an output table that looks like this:

| Variable | Value | Estimate | Low_ci | Hi_ci |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ell | 0 | 0.02185 | 0.000664 | 0.11 |
| ell | 1 | 0.0273 | 0.0034 | 0.09 |

Comment: What packages are you using (what package does the `api` dataset come from)? What is `apiclus1`?

Comment: Those are datasets in the `survey` package

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the point estimate with `as.numeric` and the confidence interval with `confint`

```
> data.frame(p=as.numeric(df), ci=confint(df))
                     p      ci.2.5.  ci.97.5.
I(ell == 0) 0.02185792 0.0006639212 0.1077784
```

I don't know what you mean about a data frame with a row for `ell==1`: `ell` is not a binary variable: it's a percentage, with quite a lot of zeros

```
> summary(apiclus1$ell)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00   16.00   26.00   27.61   37.00   73.00
```

If you had a set of confidence intervals to compute, you might use `svyby` to get them in a data frame. For example, the proportion of `ell==0` by school type:

```
> svyby(~I(ell==0),~stype, design=dclus1, svyciprop,vartype="ci")
  stype I(ell == 0)        ci_l      ci_u
E     E  0.01388889 0.001383745 0.1252329
H     H  0.07142857 0.010052692 0.3681672
M     M  0.04000000 0.003850809 0.3099199
> is.data.frame(svyby(~I(ell==0),~stype, design=dclus1, svyciprop,vartype="ci"))
[1] TRUE
```